# BrowserStack in azure devops release 'build not found'

Tags: azure-devops, browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

I have added the browserstack variables to my msttest test scripts.

We have the build being done and published in the pipeline. I added the browserstack configuration to it:

```
     inputs:
      BrowserStackServiceEndPoint: 'BrowserStack Remote Service Connection'
      browserstackLocal: true
```

I added the five Browserstack variables into this pipeline (ACCESS_KEY, BUILD_NAME, LOCAL, LOCAL_IDENTIFER, USERNAME)

I then, also tried to add the configuration and the test results to the release..for running the tests before we move our code from dev to test. I also put these variables into the Variable section. I left these blank, assuming that the code/processes take it from the program/pipeline/release. If I am wrong on this, please let me know.

[image]

When I run the tests, I am trying to see the test results in azure devops, but it is not, I am getting the following error message. I am wondering what I am missing.

*2022-09-06T15:39:20.8257875Z ##[error] Build not found by name: "azure-Test-Scheduled Automated Testing-1300*

[image]

Comment: A few questions to debug this issue:
 1. Is the browser local binary/language binding in use? (I believe LOCAL and LOCAL_IDENTIFIER must be passed in azure).
 2. On the BrowserStack dashboard, do you see any build getting triggered? And if yes, then what's the build name?

Comment: 1) The browser used is in browserstack, the test dll is on azure, does that answer that question?2) Dashboard looks like above, do I need to somehow create the name myself? Hard code it somehow? Somewhere?  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I actually got it to work, I got the build name right, in my code, and matching the variable on the release. And the browserstack results said it was successful. I got the normal looking test ressults..but no link or grid to browserstack. What am I missing now?

Comment: Does this only work/show up on pipelines? and not releases?